# Python: Writing script to scrape images off of HTTPS URL database

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I was messing around in python 3.x yesterday, and i wanted to scrape all of the images off of a HTTPS website. This is the code I have so far

```
import urllib
import urllib.request

idnum = 190154

ur = 'https://skystorage.iscorp.com/pictures/IL/Lincolnway//%d' % idnum
url = ur + '.JPG?rev=0'
filename = str(idnum) + '.JPG'

idnum = idnum + 1

try: urllib.request.urlretrieve(url , filename)
except urllib.error.URLError as e:
        print(e.reason)
```

This, however, is not working at all as planned, as the URL is HTTPS and urllib does not seem to support this. How would I be able to do something similarly to scrape the images?

Answer (score 0):

man there is much work to do,but anyway I would like to help you .
first think you should know is that if you are in a html page,first you must create a list of the urls of the image that you would like to download ,to do this you can find helpful to know what Is a regular expression and know how to use RE library of python.
With the RE you can search in the html code the urls of the image.
Then made a method that save on your computer all of image that are in the list that you have been created before.
I hope I was helpful

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'm going to make a loop to essentially scrape the entire database. I just need to know how to even access the database through python urllib doesn't allow accessing of https

Comment: publish here a code like you would like to use,aniway you must use a user agent on urllib when you use the method request , because the server where is the database allow the access only if you are a internet browser, in fact the user agent do this, simulate that the code is i.b. when it try to access at the db